# CSS gradients of the background image itself

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I want to use CSS to create a linear gradient, not of a color but of an image.

Ideally I want code that looks something along the lines of

```
background: lineargradient(135deg, Image1, Image2)
```

Similar to how it is done using colors but instead with images.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You mean interpolate the images?

Comment: I suppose, my actual task itself is just have the image fade into the background color

Comment: Not sure if that makes it simpler than pixel interpolation

Comment: Create a background image containing `<div>` and layer your gradient on top of it with a transparent-solid gradient.

Comment: That was a bit more dense than I could comprehend, you want to create a div element, and then inside put the image, and then...?

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucdd35ka/) here is an example. I can post it as an answer if it works for you.

Comment: Ohhh, put a black to clear gradient on top of the image? instead of  image fading into the background??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `svg`'s `mask` and `linearGradient` to transition between two images.

```html
<svg id="img" width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="r" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="none" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="none" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="300">
      <path d="M0,0 h600 v300 h-600z" fill="url(#r)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image width="600" height="300" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/6" />
  <image mask="url(#m)" width="600" height="300" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/2" />
</svg>
```

---

At angle `135deg`.

```html
<svg id="img" width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="r" gradientTransform="translate(600, 0) rotate(135)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="30%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="none" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="300">
      <path d="M0,0 h600 v300 h-600z" fill="url(#r)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image width="600" height="300" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/6" />
  <image mask="url(#m)" width="600" height="300" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/300/sports/2" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to add an overlay over the image with a css gradient so it appears the image is fading into the background:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="overlay">
   </div>
   <img src="http://www.placecage.com/500/200"/> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

## [**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/dc5eep8j/1/)

here's another fiddle with a matching background color:

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/dc5eep8j/2/)